# File not exists while copy from document folder to nsbundle app folder swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save xlsx file from document folder to app folder. Here is code but it showing error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “file1.xlsx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8AC91C23-3662-44FF-90EF-20F6A34AF61F/Documents/file1.xlsx, NSUnderlyingError=0x16169a60 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

```
let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL( documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
let xlsxFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "xlsx" }
let xlsxFileNames = mp3Files.flatMap({$0.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent})

var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

do {
    try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(xlsxFiles[0].absoluteString, toPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + xlsxFileNames[0] + ".xlsx")
}
catch let error 
{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: On a device, the application bundle is readonly.  Why do you think the file should be in the bundle?

Comment: Run on simulator and check manually if file exists.

Comment: @PhillipMills he must have put that file in bundle file creating project.

Comment: @meet adding file to project doesn't ensure that it's added to bundle, you will need to add the file to target too.

Comment: @PhillipMills
https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter using this library which opens file from bundle only 

this is how this library finds path of excel file 

NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testWorkbook", ofType: "xlsx")

any idea what should i do ?

Comment: @NikhilManapure i am trying to import the excel file which user selects .. and the library which i am using i have mentioned in earlier comment please see and advice

Comment: Give the library a different path?

Comment: @PhillipMills is this path ("file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A89‌​9A1B1-A50B-423D-965C‌​-87089301070A/Docume‌​nts/Contacttoexcelpr‌​o.xlsx") accessable ??

Comment: I guess you are confusing Documents folder to bundle, is it so?

Comment: yes i m not confused .. actually i dont know about it much . accepting what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. The first one is causing the error you posted in your question.

1. Both parameters to `copyItemAtPath` need to be full file paths. Your first argument is just a file name. You need to append the file name to a full path to its location (similar to what you do for the second argument).
2. The app's bundle is read-only. You can't copy a file to your app's bundle. So even once you fix the first problem, you will have a new problem. If the file is already inside your app's Documents folder, why do you try to copy it to the bundle?

Comment: po mp3Files[0].absoluteString

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3CB10230-8A89-4F9C-A99E-F55630435424/Documents/Contacttoexcelpro.xlsx`

This is how third party library read xlsx file 

`var documentPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testWorkbook", ofType: "xlsx")
var spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(documentPath)`

i want to open file from this path 

`"file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3CB10230-8A89-4F9C-A99E-F55630435424/Documents/Contacttoexcelpro.xlsx"`

but its not working

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. Be sure to format the code as code so we can read it.